# "korrekt" oder "richtig"

Tags: word-choice

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "korrekt" und "richtig"?

> Dieser Satz ist **korrekt**.
>
> Die Schüler mussten feststellen, ob die Aussagen **richtig** waren.

Kann man sie in diesen Beispielen austauschen oder sie beziehen sich auf verschiedene Eigenschaften?

Comment: Basically the same as the difference between "correct" and "right" in English. "This sentence is correct/right."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Die beiden Wörter sind in so gut wie allen Fällen austauschbar.

Vorzugsweise (aber nicht ausschließlich!) wird *korrekt* wird für eine objektive (formal definierte) Korrektheit verwendet, *richtig* für eine subjektive (moralische) Korrektheit.

Damit kann man in bestimmten Situationen einen Gegensatz zwischen diesen beiden Wertungsebenen herausstellen:

> Die Hinrichtung des Mannes war **korrekt** (die Gesetze verlangten es so), aber nicht **richtig** (ich halte sie für verwerflich).
>
> Die Hinrichtung des Mannes war **richtig** (ich finde es gut, dass sie passierte), aber nicht **korrekt** (es wurden Verfahrensfehler gemacht).

Wenn sie einzeln auftreten, sind die beiden Wörter aber grundsätzlich synonym.

> Dieser Satz ist **richtig**.
>
> Die Schüler mussten feststellen, ob die Aussagen **korrekt** waren.

..sind beide völlig korrekt/richtig und haben unverändert die gleiche Bedeutung wie deine Beispiele.

Comment: Wobei interessanterweise in der Jugendsprache *korrekt* auch eher die Bedeutung von *richtig* annimmt.

Answer (score 2):

> In allen Lebenslagen: Heinz ist ein korrekter Mensch.

*»Korrekt«* heißt hier so viel wie *»so, wie man es von einem anständigen Bürger erwartet«* und kann nicht durch *»richtig«* ersetzt werden.

> Ein richtiges Essen besteht aus Vor-, Haupt- und Nachspeise.

*»Richtig«* heißt hier so viel wie *»vollständig«* und kann nicht durch *»korrekt«* ersetzt werden¹.
<sub>¹Höchstens umgangssprachlich</sub>

Comment: Alles soweit richtig, allerdings wurde nicht auf die Beispiele des Fragestellers eingegangen.

Comment: @RHa: Sehe ich auch so, ist mehr eine Ergänzung, hatte Annatars Behandlung der Beispiel-Frage nichts hinzuzufügen.